# jQuery UI Radio Buttons - different colours for each selection?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I'm using jQuery UIs radio buttons with the [Aristo](http://taitems.github.com/Aristo-jQuery-UI-Theme/) theme and they're fantastic.

The problem is, I have two radio buttons with two options, 'Approve' and 'Reject' - if approve is selected, I want the button to be blue, which is how it is at the moment which is great. But if I select 'Reject' I'd like the button to go red (and approve go grey, as it does)

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="toggle">
    <input type="radio" id="approve" name="approved" checked /><label for="approve">Approve</label>
    <input type="radio" id="reject" name="approved" /><label for="reject">Reject</label>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#reject .ui-button.ui-state-focus {
    background: url(images/bg_red.png) repeat-x;
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

The CSS isn't targeting the label at all, I guess because it's an overlay created by jQuery UI, so a long shot, but is there a way to change the colour depending on selection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
$('#approve').change(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
   {
      $(this).addClass('blue');
      $('#reject').removeClass('red');
   }
});

$('#reject').change(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
   {
      $(this).addClass('red');
      $('#approve').removeClass('blue');
   }
});
```

Comment: Many thanks, unfortunately this doesn't work though since it just applies the class to the radio button, not the label overlay.